# Full screen issue

Tags: display

I just finished to set up my new desktop computer (i9-9900K and RTX 2080, with 2 27" screens) on which I installed ElementaryOS.
I'll mainly use it for development, but also to play a bit (on Steam).
Everything works fine (good job on that!), execpt when an app is in full screen mode. It's completely frozen, until I click outside of the window.

Example:

- open PHPStorm, switch to full screen
- click on a file to open it => nothing happens
- click on the other screen (PHPStorm loses focus) => PHPStorm view is updated, and the file is opened

Tried with different apps, it's always the same behavior.
Got nvidia drivers 415 properly installed.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Whenever I set a video to fullscreen, the window freezes.